# с# Telegram API, TgSharp Получить текст сообщения с форматированием

Tags: c#, telegram

С помощью библиотеки TgSharp могу получить пост на канале:`

```
     TLChannelMessages resp = (TLChannelMessages)await client.GetHistoryAsync(new TLInputPeerChannel()
            {
                ChannelId = project.channel.Id,
                AccessHash = project.channel.AccessHash ?? 0,
            }, limit: 10);

            var msgs = resp.Messages;
            

            TLMessage lastMessage = (TLMessage)resp.Messages?.Where(x => x is TLMessage).First();

        var Message = lastMessage.Message; // Текст поста
```

Пример поста текст которого я хочу получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст я получаю без форматирования (курсив, жирный шрифт).
Как можно сохранить текст с исходным форматированием?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, может кому-то будет полезно:

Получаем посты, lastMessage - последний опубликованый пост:

```
TLChannelMessages resp = (TLChannelMessages)await client.GetHistoryAsync(new TLInputPeerChannel()
        {
            ChannelId = project.channel.Id,
            AccessHash = project.channel.AccessHash ?? 0,
        }, limit: 10);

        var msgs = resp.Messages;
        

        TLMessage lastMessage = (TLMessage)resp.Messages?.Where(x => x is TLMessage).First();

    var Message = lastMessage.Message; // Текст поста

 var Entities = lastMessage.Entities;



      }



var Entities = lastMessage.Entities;


                        foreach (var Entitie in Entities)
                            switch (Entitie)
                            {

                                case TLMessageEntityBold Bold:

                                    MessageBox.Show(lastMessage.Message.Substring(Bold.Offset, Bold.Length));
                                     break;

                                case TLMessageEntityItalic Italic:
                                    MessageBox.Show(lastMessage.Message.Substring(Italic.Offset, Italic.Length));
                                    break;


                            }
```

Comment: вам самому будет гораздо проще жить, если вы научитесь форматировать свой код